# Custom Cloud Shell Image Creation - git push problem

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm creating a custom Google **Cloud Shell** image.
 I'm following Cloud Shell's own tutorial on how to create a custom image.
 Everything was fine to the step: *Push image to Google Container Registry.*

```
$ git commit -a -m "Initial custom environment check-in."

[master 4d63b1d] Initial custom environment check-in.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 2 deletions(-)

$ git push origin master

fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: You need to specify (add) the origin for git: `git remote add origin https://...` You did not specify a link to the article so I don't know the URL to add. You will need to look that up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going in that direction.
What is the problem with people who do an incomplete tutorial?

Comment: I have written numerous tutorials. It is easy to leave out something that is required. Going thru your tutorial step-by-step is required to make sure the "dumb" items are included. This includes using a virgin machine so that artifacts such as already installed libraries are detected. This is an extra quality control step that we sometimes forget to do. A good quality tutorial takes a lot of effort.

Comment: When I or you do a tutorial it is normal to escape something, but an official Google tutorial within the GCP platform (which they want to sell) is somewhat discouraged. But we keep walking, never giving up!